# I am getting weird error in my django app

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, django-dynamic-scraper

I am trying to use Django dynamic scraper in my app and when I try to run the server I get this error message

```
RuntimeError: Model class dynamic_scraper.models.ScrapedObjClass doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

but I have this in my installed apps

```
dynamic_scraper
```

What seems to be the issue?

### EDIT

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
      'django.contrib.admin',
      'django.contrib.auth',
      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
      'django.contrib.sessions',
      'django.contrib.messages',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles',

      # local
      'blog',

      # Third party
      'crispy_forms',
      'taggit',
      'haystack',
      'whoosh',
      'pagedown',
      'markdown_deux',
      'dynamic_scraper'
  )
```

Comment: what version of django are you using? and can you post the contents of the dynamic_scraper app directory?

Comment: @nkhumphreys I fixed it. I have a settings directory with base.py, local and production. I only put dynamic scraper in my base thinking it would import into my production and base. it didn't I had to ad it to each one.

Comment: @lose you can set it up so that you have an INSTALLED_APPS_BASE, then have ```INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS_BASE + ('foo_app',) ``` in your development settings and again in production settings to reduce duplication. There is some good stuff on this in the 2 scoops of Django book

Comment: @luke_austhat book seemed a bit advanced for me. I need to go to a pycon or django con if they ever have one in ct,nj, or ny so I can have a pro go over somethings. Thanks for the response though